# Sending parameters from an anchor tag in angular js

Tags: php, html, angularjs

My php website has an anchor tag (inside a button) which sends a number to the Angular app;

```
echo "<button data-toggle='tooltip' type='submit' data-placement='bottom' title='$description' class='button-modal' style='float:right; color:white; background:grey; padding:0px; margin:3px; border:0px; border-radius:50%; top:7px; right:".$right."px !important;  width:30px; height:30px; font-size:10px' type='submit'><input TYPE=hidden name='caseID' value='$caseID'><a href='#!$caseID?caseID=$caseID' style='color:white'>$first_letter</a></button>";
```

To simplify things, anchor tag is;

```
<a href='#!$caseID?caseID=$caseID' style='color:white'>$first_letter</a>
```

The data in `#!$caseID` is an integer 00001, 00002, 00003... which triggers the routing.

**This all works**

The Angularjs part of the code is;

```
<script>

var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        template : ""
    })
    .when("/00001", {
        templateUrl : "includes/index.php"
    })
    .when("/00002", {
        templateUrl : "includes/index.php"
    })
    .when("/00003", {
        templateUrl : "includes/index.php"
    })
    .when("/00004", {
        templateUrl : "includes/index.php"
    })
    .when("/00005", {
        templateUrl : "includes/index.php"
    })
    .when("/00006", {
        templateUrl : "includes/index.php"
    })
});
</script>
```

**PROBLEM No.1** : I need a way to include the parameter data from $caseID (that is the int 00001, 00002...)
**?caseID=$caseID** in the route, along with the templateUrl.

**PROMBLEM No.2** : THEN I need to store the integer from the angularjs param data in a php variable in index.php, probably by way of $_GET['caseID'];

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass parameters via url, if you have a query string like this html://mysite.com/myroute?caseID=0001, you can capture the value in the route declaration.

```
$routeProvider
.when("/", {
  template : ""
})
.when("/myroute?caseID", {
  templateUrl : "includes/index01.php"
  params: {
    caseID: null
  }
})
```

Check the documentation https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-parameters

Get url params in an AngularJs component controller. In your case nor clear as setting the `templateUrl` to a `.php` file is not clear to me.

```
// inject $stateParams service (ui-router 4.x) into AngularJs controller
function MyController($stateParams) {
  var caseID = $stateParams.caseID;
  // use your url param
}
```

Maybe you can provide more context about your issue.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Any idea how you would then pass the data from caseID inside the parameter to index01.php?  Is it by way of $_GET['caseID']

Comment: Thanks again.  The route app opens index01.php by way of templateUrl - I need to also set a php variable in index01.php with the caseID variable.